# prevent modal dialog from closing - VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-sdk, vssdk

I want to prevent [modal dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/reference/client/controls/modaldialog?view=vsts) from closing when the 'x' button on upper left corner is clicked.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can’t.  I can define a global variable to identify whether the modal dialog is closed by click X button or not. (Change the value in button event)

Comment: VSS.getService(VSS.ServiceIds.Dialog).then(function(dialogService) { var contributionId = //id var dialogOptions = { title: "ABC", close: onDialogCloseByCrossButtonClick }; dialogService.openDialog(contributionId, dialogOptions).then(function (dialog) {}); this is my code.. where I can change value

Comment: its sdk provides some functions that called after dialog is closed when 'X' button is clicked, I want an event before modal dialog is closed.

Comment: I mean change the variable value in the button function (e.g. Ok button)